# pausing vimeo video onmouseleave

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I am trying to pause my videos onmouseleave of the iframe, but it doesn’t work, only the alert. Any idea why?

```
<iframe
  class='iframe-video'
  onmouseleave='pauseVideo();'
  name='iframe-<?php print($key)?>'
  id='iframe-<?= $project->num() ?>'
  width='1000'
  height='563'
  frameborder='0'
  webkitallowfullscreen
  mozallowfullscreen
  allowfullscreen
></iframe>;

function pauseVideo() {
  alert('it works');
  var video = $('#iframe-<?= $project->num() ?>');
  var player = new Vimeo.Player(video);

  player.pause();
}
```